# python networkx connectionstyle arc3 gives me strange result

Tags: python, networkx

I want to make a circular network graph with nodes linked by an arc
I just started using networkx

I found the correct ways of doing arcs for my edges but some of them have an inverted curve ...

here is the full code

```
import random
from math import cos, sin
import matplotlib
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pyvis.network import Network
import scipy as sp


def get_coordinates_in_circle(n, scale):
    return_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        theta = float(i) / n * 2 * 3.141592654

        y = cos(theta)
        x = sin(theta)
        return_list.append((x * scale, y * scale))
        # print(return_list)
    return return_list


def draw_number(length):
    """determines a random index number for selection."""
    from_index = random.randint(0, length)
    to_index = random.randint(0, length)
    return from_index, to_index


def netw(NodesN):
    G = nx.Graph()

    node_list = []
    fixed_positions = {}  # dict with two of the positions set
    for i in range(1, NodesN + 1):
        node_list.append(i)
    CirclePos = get_coordinates_in_circle(NodesN, 1)
  
    # jump by 1
    from_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    to_list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]

    # jump by 2
    from_list2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
    to_list2 =   [3,5,7,9,1]

    # jump by 3
    from_list3 = [1,4,7,10,3 ]
    to_list3 =   [4,7,10,3,6]
    from_list = from_list1
    to_list = to_list1
    
    for i in range(len(node_list)):
        G.add_node(node_list[i])
        fixed_positions[i+1] = CirclePos[i]
    for j in range(len(from_list)):
        G.add_edges_from([(from_list[j], to_list[j])])
    fixed_nodes = fixed_positions.keys()
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, pos=fixed_positions, fixed=fixed_nodes)
    # pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G, pos=fixed_positions)


    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,arrows=True,connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad=.5")
    # nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)
    plt.show()

netw(10)
```

it gives me the correct thing except for the 10->1 edge
and if I change the "jump by" list the problem change place and make the "inverted" arc when an edge goes from a big number to a small number

I understood part of my problem with this
to replace my coordinates in the "get_coordinates_in_circle" func

it just gives me a line instead of a circle (not what I want just an aid to understant my problem)

```
return_list = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8),(0,9),]
```

my question is: is ther a way to make it thinks its a closed loop?

draw_circular does not do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency in the arc direction comes from the fact that you're using a `Graph` instead of a `DiGraph`. If we change the first line of the `netw` function definition to `G = nx.Graph()`, we end up with the following:

[image]

Also, if you want to invert the curvature of the edges, you can use a negative number for rad in the connectionstyle specification. For instance, using `connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad=-.5"` yields the following result:

[image]

---

By the way, here's a refactored version of your code.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def netw(NodesN, jump = 1):
    node_list = list(range(1,NodesN + 1))
    
    from_list = node_list[::jump]
    to_list = from_list[1:] + from_list[:1]

#
# I suspect you're actually trying to do this with the "jump by" number:
#
#     from_list = node_list
#     to_list = from_list[jump:] + from_list[:jump]
    
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(node_list)
    G.add_edges_from(zip(from_list, to_list))
    
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    
# If you really want the nodes to go clockwise starting from the top, here's a quick approach.
# Just uncomment the block below
#    
#     c,s = pos[node_list[0]]
#     R_mat = np.array([[-s,c],[c,s]])
#     for k,v in pos.items():
#         pos[k] = R_mat @ v    
    
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, connectionstyle=f"arc3,rad=.5")
    plt.show()


netw(10, jump = 1)
```